# ValueError: Class label 1 not present when specifying class_weight in RandomForestClassifier with k-fold cv

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm doing a binary classification on time-series data. Since it's for an academic project, I want to test classical ML models such as RandomForestClassifier as well.

However, while using TimeSeriesSplit K-fold Cross-Validation, it is possible that while training; labels have only one class instead of both, which is raising `ValueError`.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight={1:10, 0:1})
rfc.fit([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]], [0, 0])
```

This gives,
`ValueError: Class label 1 not present.`

I know it doesn't make sense to train with only one label, but then it works fine if we don't specify `class_weight`. Is this a bug?

How do I get around this programmatically if I'm automating my testing?

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback.  Ideally, if you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (including a dataset), it would help us find exactly where the error gets raised and how to work around it.

Comment: Also, to your last question (how to bypass the error in automated testing), it probably depends on how exactly your automatic testing works; provide some code for that too.

Comment: @BenReiniger thanks for suggestions, however; the given code *is* minimal reproducible example. I've raised the issue on sklearn's github and it seems to be a bug, more updates at https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/22413

Comment: Ah, I was focused on your time series setting, and hadn't noticed you gave the simple example. I agree that performing the check only for weights is weird, so I would expect the suggested fix to go smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue has been [fixed on 11 Mar 2022](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/22413).

I am able to run below code without any problem today:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight={1:10, 0:1})
rfc.fit([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]], [0, 1])
rfc.predict([[1, 1, 1]])

Output: array([1])


rfc.fit([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]], [0, 0])
rfc.predict([[1, 1, 1]])

Output: array([0])
```

Comment: Yes, I had raised this issue, and it has been consequently fixed!